# What is actually internally happening in python when a=10,

Tags: python

I am learning python where i come across below scenario

what actually happening internally in python can someone brief

**My code :**

```
a=10,
print(a)
```

**Output coming as :**

```
(10,)
```

Comment: `10,` is a tuple of one element, which is canonically represented as `(10,)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a=10,` is a `tuple`:

You can easily determine the type of the `a` using the `type` function as follows:

```py
type(a)
```

Use `a[0]` to access the value `10`:

```py
a=10,
print(a[0])
```